# Помощь в решении

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуста.

Даны числа a, b, c, d. Если `a < b < c < d`, то каждое число заменить наименьшим, если `a  > b > c > d`, то каждое число уменьшить на 40%, в противном случае оставить числа без изменения.

Код программы:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <windows.h>
include <conio.h>
include <math.h>

main() { 
    float a,b,c,d; 
    if (a < b && b < c && c < d) {
        b=a; c=a; d=a; 
    } 
    else if (a > b && b > c && c > d); { 
        a=a-a*0.4; 
        b=b-b*0.4; 
        c=c-c*0.4; 
        d=d-d*0.4; 
    } 
    printf("a=%f b=%f c=%f d=%f", a,b,c,d); 
    fflush(stdin); 
    getchar(); 
    return(0); 
}
```

Comment: Где ваш код, где ваши мысли, где конкретика?..

Comment: Не понятно: вам надо помочь, или сделать за вас задание? Если второе, то не по адресу. Если первое, то надо писать: "Было сделано то-то, но то-то не вышло, помогите найти ошибку". Примерно так.

Comment: и как, работает?

Comment: только лучше все это запихнуть в текст вопроса и отформатировать, а заодно изменить сам вопрос

Comment: вижу несколько ошибок.

1. после блока условий после else if не нужен знак ";"

2. оператор умножения - *. и лучше сразу умножить переменные на 0.6.

еще вопрос : откуда берутся значения переменных?

Comment: Не очень хорошо он работает только "a" с адектватными числами  a "b" "c"и  "d" вообще одни нули

Comment: @Pycbka, переместил ваш код в вопрос, у вас там есть несколько очевидных ошибок, добавленных, наверно, во время комментирования, исправьте их сами.

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса. Код есть, в нем только две тривиальные ошибки (1.инициализируйте переменные; 2.уберите ';', как верно заметил @mikillskegg, плюс тип ф-кции main впишите int), которые видно невооруженным глазом и без компиляции...
Кроме того, если можно обойтись без лишнего #include -- обходись.

Comment: Как понять инициализируйте?

Comment: инициализировать переменные - присвоить ей явным образом значение, т.е. поместить данные в соответствующие ячейки памяти. если этого не сделать и использовать неинициализированную переменную в выражении, можно легко получит ошибку, т.к. там может находиться все, что угодно, особенно в локальных переменных, находящихся в сетке.

Comment: Вас сложно сложно понятнь, т.к. особо я не разбираюсь. Помойму проще было бы строчку эту написать. Что мне надо инициализировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  float a,b,c,d;

  for (;;) {
    char str[1024];
    printf ("Enter  a,b,c,d > "); fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%f %f %f %f",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4)
      break;
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
  }
  printf ("%f %f %f %f\n",a,b,c,d);

}
```

Пример ввода 4-х чисел типа float. Вставьте в начало своей программы.

Answer (score 1):

Так в чем проблема? Алгоритм очень простой. Проверяете переменные на соответствие указанным условиям, и если они выполняются, производите соответствующие действия. Если нет - ничего не делаете. Вам код нужен? Напишите хоть что-нибудь. Если будет ошибка, исправим и обсудим.

Comment: к вопросу об инициализации переменных. примеры:

1. int a = 7;

2. int a = c + b;

3. int a; scanf ("%d", &a);

стало понятнее?

Comment: Хотя бы один пример, где в моей программе это надо вставить.